# Will Skype4Com stop working in 2014?

Tags: c#, skype4com

I'm trying to develop Skype application. Skype said that's it's API will stop working at the end of 2013. will Skype4Com or Skype4lib also stop working?

Comment: **Do those libraries use the Skype API?**

Comment: How should we know? This is a question for Skype's support team (or Google).

Comment: The only programmatic access to skype on the http://dev.skype.com/ page seem to be for 'buttons', or "skype uri's", to allow you to initiate a skype chat.  That's pretty much it, I suspect.

Answer (score 2):

http://gigaom.com/2013/07/13/skype-says-it-will-kill-desktop-api-by-end-of-2013/
http://aragonresearch.com/microsoft-kills-skype-desktop-apis-leaves-developers-scrambling/

So, in summary, it seems that it will stop working.

Comment: I think like that, the SkypeKit will stop working, but is the Skype4com will also stop?

Comment: Do some research. Can you find any documentation or reference by the skype developers (ie, Microsoft)?  Yes? Then what does it say. If you can't find any documentation, then you can only assume that it is unsupported.